# Creating a class in react and exporting with higher order components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a class in React and exporting it with a higher order component, presently I have ...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter }       from 'react-router';


/**
    Project Editor
*/
class SpiceEditorRaw extends Component { ... }

const SpiceEditor = withRouter(SpiceEditorRaw);    
export default SpiceEditor;
```

Then In a different file I import `SpiceEditor` and subclass it with

```
import SpiceEditor from './SpiceEditor'

class NameEditor extends SpiceEditor {

    constructor(props){ ... } 

    ...
    render () { return (<h1> hello world <h1/>) }

}
```

However I am getting error:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: The <withRouter(SpiceEditorRaw) /> component appears to have a render method, but doesn't extend React.Component. This is likely to cause errors. Change withRouter(SpiceEditorRaw) to extend React.Component instead.
```

I believe it is possible to create a `compoenent` using `withRouter`, so I must be syntaxing incorrectly?

Comment: You should generally not use `extends` on any other component than `React.Component`. I think the [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance) part of the documentation is a great read on this subject.

Comment: You should try just rendering `<SpiceEditor />` instead of extending it and see if it works.

Comment: ok @Tholle I went for your suggestion.if you write it up in an answer I'll check resolve.d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generally not use `extends` on any other component than `React.Component`. I think the [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance) part of the documentation is a great read on this subject.

You can accomplish almost everything with composition instead.

**Example**

```
import SpiceEditor from './SpiceEditor'

class NameEditor extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <SpiceEditor>
        { /* ... */ }
      </SpiceEditor>
    )
  }
}
```